# CKAccountStatus when not using iCloudDrive?

Tags: cloudkit

I'm working with CloudKit.  I use this code to check to see if the user is logged into iCloud.

```
[[CKContainer containerWithIdentifier:my.container.id] 
   accountStatusWithCompletionHandler:^(CKAccountStatus accountStatus, NSError *error) {
  // check accountStatus         
}];
```

However, the account status comes back as `CKAccountStatusNoAccount` if I'm logged in, but have iCloud Drive turned off.  I would expect it to be `CKAccountStatusAvailable` instead, as I'm not using iCloud Drive here.

Is there a way to check if the user is logged in regardless of iCloud Drive usage?

Comment: Very useful info if trying to use the latest iOS 13 `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer ` feature. If iCloud Drive is disabled, then the "automatic" syncing will not occur because `CKAccountStatusNoAccount` returns false and effectively disables it.

Answer (score 0):

This code checks to see if a user is authorized to access iCloud. This will work.

```
 func isAuthorized4Cloud() {
    appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    container = CKContainer(identifier: "iCloud.ch.cqd.presenTagger")
    publicDB = container.publicCloudDatabase
    privateDB = container.privateCloudDatabase
    var userID: CKRecordID!
    container.fetchUserRecordID( completionHandler: { recordID, error in
        guard error == nil else {
            if let ckerror = error as? CKError {
                if ckerror.code == CKError.requestRateLimited {
                    let retryInterval = ckerror.userInfo[CKErrorRetryAfterKey] as? TimeInterval
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: retryInterval!, target: self, selector: #selector(self.files_searchSet), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
                    }
                } else if ckerror.code == CKError.zoneBusy {
                    let retryInterval = ckerror.userInfo[CKErrorRetryAfterKey] as? TimeInterval
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: retryInterval!, target: self, selector: #selector(self.files_searchSet), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
                    }
                } else if ckerror.code == CKError.limitExceeded {
                    let retryInterval = ckerror.userInfo[CKErrorRetryAfterKey] as? TimeInterval
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: retryInterval!, target: self, selector: #selector(self.files_searchSet), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
                    }
                } else if ckerror.code == CKError.notAuthenticated {
                    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("noCloud"), object: nil, userInfo: nil)
                } else if ckerror.code == CKError.networkFailure {
                    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("networkFailure"), object: nil, userInfo: nil)
                } else if ckerror.code == CKError.networkUnavailable {
                    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("noWiFi"), object: nil, userInfo: nil)
                } else if ckerror.code == CKError.quotaExceeded {
                    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("quotaExceeded"), object: nil, userInfo: nil)
                } else if ckerror.code == CKError.partialFailure {
                    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("partialFailure"), object: nil, userInfo: nil)
                } else if (ckerror.code == CKError.internalError || ckerror.code == CKError.serviceUnavailable) {
                    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("serviceUnavailable"), object: nil, userInfo: nil)
                }
            } // end of guard statement
            return
        }

        if error == nil {
            userID = recordID
            //print("fcuk1210 files_setup userID \(userID.recordName)")
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("cloudConnected"), object: nil, userInfo: nil)
        }
    })
}
```